# Wrong links on wingpanel for network settings [solved]

Tags: wingpanel

When I press:
Network (top panel) -> "Network settings"
then, it opens "System Settings" instead of "Network settings".
Same thing was with "Date & Time Settings...", but now works properly.

So what kind of magic should I do to fix it? Can you help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new release of the network settings plug that came out today (Sep 15th 2017) that should resolve this issue.

Comment: Now is ok. Thx)